# YouTube API V2 Quota Limits

Tags: youtube-api

**For V2 of the YouTube Data API what are the exact limits for the quota?**

I am aware that this is a frequent question, however I am yet to find any concrete answers.

---

Reason for Question:

I am going to querying a large pool of videos for their comments on a regular basis and would like to know when I am coming close to my quota limit, so the system can slow down. In V3 of the YouTube API, the quota limits are clearly [documented](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=en#quota). However I'm unable to use V3 of the API as it does not support the retrieval of comments *(sidenote - does anyone know why?)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v2 of the data API, the quota was not a fixed number per day as it is in v3, but instead was a limit that prevented too many requests within a short period of time. Unfortunately, I don't believe that there exists anywhere some firm documentation as to how many requests that would be or what the short period of time would be, either; generally, Youtube has always stated that if you get a quota error while making a call to v2 of the data API you should wait "a few minutes" before trying again. Here's the only official statement.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses?hl=en#Quota_errors

It is possible that one of the reasons for this lack of direct documentation is that there isn't a hard and fast number, but it changes in response to the current load.

In answer to your side question, there haven't been any official statements from the YouTube team about why comment retrieval hasn't yet been implemented, but it likely will be in time (as will other pieces of data retrievable via v2 but not yet via v3).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good idea about there not being a fixed number, as it may depend on current load.

+1 - however I really want a reply from one of the @YouTubeDev team...

Comment: It has been answered by youtube on the former youtube api forum. In short: There is no hard limit they tell you and one should follow the suggestion as mentioned above. To maybe have it added to V3, you should file an Enhancement here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-YouTube (after checking first that there is not one already filed). Others can "vote it up" requesting more priority, if the request is accepted.

Comment: Added an enhancement request, please vote it up - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5046&thanks=5046&ts=1376562250